# async waterfall not saving correctly with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async.js

This is my first time working with async and although i have searched the web and tried both the series and waterfall methods, my results are the same. I think i am pretty close to having this work correctly but just cant get it to work 100%.

I am attempting to create a test based upon time and test question parameters sent from the front end.The main issue is that the final method at the bottom which creates the test is taking place before middle method which searches for the questions, sample answers if there are any, and then places it in an array of objects.

Once completed, test is being created with no questions in it, but it does save the time from the first function.  Initially(before trying async) i wrapped the "new interviewtest" method in a 2sec setTimeout and this worked fine but i know there is a better, more efficient way to do this.

```
exports.create = function(req) {
console.log(req.body);
var testTime = 0;
var timer = req.body.timeValue;
var testQuestions = req.body.category;
var finalQuestions = [];

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) { **add total time into one value to be saved in the test**
        for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) {
            if (timer[i] !== '') {
                testTime += parseInt(timer[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(null,testTime);
    },
    function(testTime,callback) { **find question and push it into array of objects**
        for (var i = 0; i < testQuestions.length; i++) {
            allTestQuestions.findById(testQuestions[i], function(err, result) {
                var test = {};
                test.text = result.text;
                test.answer = '';
                test.sample = result.sample;
                finalQuestions.push(test);
            });
        }   
        callback(null, testTime, finalQuestions);
    },
    function(testTime, finalQuestions, callback) { **create new test**
        new interviewTest({
            authCode: req.body.intAuthCode,
            name: req.body.intName,
            questions: finalQuestions, **questions**
            assignedDate: new Date,
            started: false,
            startedTime: '1970',
            completed: false,
            completedTime: '1970',
            time: testTime,
            timePerQuestion: []
        }).save(function(err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            if (!err) { console.log(res + " saved!"); } 
        });

        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) { callback(err); }
    console.log(result);
});
}
```

Comment: You are always calling `callback` immediately, despite having started an asynchronous function. You need to pass the callback into that, like `.save(callback);`! And for that for loop, you'll need to nest an `async.map`.

Comment: `if (err) { callback(err); }` makes no sense. There is no `callback` in that scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the middle function you have a for loop which is calling database and you are calling callback outside the loop. It should be wrapped in another async function. Try `async.each` or as Bergi suggests, `async.map`

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) {
            if (timer[i] !== '') {
                testTime += parseInt(timer[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(null,testTime);
    },
   function(testTime,callback) {
    async.each(testQuestions, function(tQuestion, eachCallback){
        allTestQuestions.findById(tQuestion, function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                // you can either eachCallback(err) or just console.log it and keep going
            }
            var test = {};
            test.text = result.text;
            test.answer = '';
            test.sample = result.sample;
            finalQuestions.push(test);
            eachCallback()
        })
    }, function(err, result){
        callback(null, testTime, finalQuestions);
    })
},
    function(testTime, finalQuestions, callback) {
        new interviewTest({
            authCode: req.body.intAuthCode,
            name: req.body.intName,
            questions: finalQuestions,
            assignedDate: new Date,
            started: false,
            startedTime: '1970',
            completed: false,
            completedTime: '1970',
            time: testTime,
            timePerQuestion: []
        }).save(function(err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                if (!err) { console.log(res + " saved!"); }
                callback(null, 'done'); //call here
            });

      //  callback(null, 'done'); this should always be called inside the callback function
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) { callback(err); }
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You really should be using `async.map` instead of `async.each`. That'll get you the `finalQuestions` implicitly.

Comment: This seems to have put me on the right track, however, i am now getting an error stating "Invalid select() argument. Must be string or object." After looking it up, I have added the async.map in lieu of the foreach.

Comment: mistakenly `allTestQuestions.findById` was taking two callback functions. Updated the answer.

Comment: @TalhaAwan everything works perfectly now! Thank you for the help, i will be able to model my future async work against this so i can learn more moving forward :)

Answer (score 0):

Callback are outside async function (save, and findById), do stg like this :

```
function(testTime,callback) { **find question and push it into array of objects**
    for (var i = 0; i < testQuestions.length; i++) {
        allTestQuestions.findById(testQuestions[i], function(err, result) {
            ...
            finalQuestions.push(test);
            if(finalQuestions.length == testQuestions.length)
                return callback(null, testTime, finalQuestions);
        });
    }   

},
function(testTime, finalQuestions, callback) { **create new test**
    new interviewTest({
      ...
    }).save(function(err, res) {
        console.log(err);
        if (!err) { console.log(res + " saved!"); } 
        callback(null, 'done');
    });
}
```